# Как можно реализовать условие в условии в телеграм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Пишу бота с помощью библиотеки `PyTelegramBotApi`.

Как можно реализовать условие в условии?

Сейчас на сообщение "мужской"  выводит "Извините, у вас другой город".
А нужно, чтобы отвечал "Йоу, у тебя получилось!"

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def answer_to_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Укажите город, в котором вы проживаете.')
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def answer_to_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'минск':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Укажите ваш пол (мужской/женский)')
        if message.text.lower() == 'мужской':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Йоу, у тебя получилось!')
        elif message.text.lower() == 'женский':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тоже нормально!')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Извините, у вас другой город!")
```

Answer (score 3):

Легче чем Вы думаете)

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def answer_to_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Укажите город, в котором вы проживаете.')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def answer_to_text(message):
    global gorod_set
    if message.text.lower() == 'минск':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Укажите ваш пол (мужской/женский)')
        gorod_set = 1
    elif message.text.lower() == 'мужской' and gorod_set == 1:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Йоу, у тебя получилось!')
        # Если нужно изменить город и начать по новой добавьте 'gorod_set = 0'
    elif message.text.lower() == 'женский' and gorod_set == 1:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тоже нормально!')
        # Здесь так же 'gorod_set = 0'
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Извините, у вас другой город!")
```

Answer (score 2):

я бы использовал `bot.register_next_step_handler` для выполнения сценария шагов:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Укажите город, в котором вы проживаете.')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_2, 'start')


def start_2(message, where_call, city=None):
    if where_call == 'start':
        town = message.text
    else:
        town = city

    print('указанный город s2:', town)
    if town == 'минск':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Укажите ваш пол (мужской/женский)')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_3, town)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Извините, у вас другой город!")
        start(message)


def start_3(message, town):
    print('указанный город s3:', town)
    print('указанный пол s3:', message.text)
    if message.text.lower() == 'мужской':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Йоу, у тебя получилось!')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'женский':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тоже нормально!')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Либо мужской либо женский")
        start_2(message, 'start_3', city=town)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```